# Writing files on heroku dyno filesystem to be used later?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I know the heroku filesystem is ephemeral.

The files I'm writing are captchas, mp3s, and other images that only need to be in the file system for a few minutes.

But I can't get anything to work right.

For the captchas, here's the code:

```
def new(request):

    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

    image = ImageCaptcha()
    alphanum_str = '0123456789ABCDEF'
    captcha_answer = ''.join(
            random.choice(alphanum_str) for i in range(5))
    timestamp = str(datetime.now().timestamp())

    image.write(captcha_answer, os.path.join(
            settings.BASE_DIR, f'hendrixia/static/captchas/{timestamp}.png'))

    context = {
        'captcha_timestamp': timestamp
    }

    r.set(f'id-{timestamp}', captcha_answer)
    r.expire(f'id-{timestamp}', 300)
    template_name = 'the_axis/new.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

The problem is at the `image.write()` line. It's using this package: https://github.com/lepture/captcha

I've tried `hendrixia/staticfiles/captchas`, `hendrixia/media/captchas`, `staticfiles/captchas`, `temp_captchas/` and others. And yes, I did make sure that those directories existed at the heroku dyno (I placed an empty `a.txt` in each).

Can anyone help with this?

Error Message / Traceback:

```
2022-03-04T11:09:39.412897+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-03-04 11:09:39,412 DEBUG    HTTP b'GET' request for ['10.1.93.196', 30646]
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440527+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-03-04 11:09:39,424 ERROR    Internal Server Error: /the-axis/new/
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440529+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440537+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440537+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440540+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440540+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440540+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440541+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440541+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./the_axis/views.py", line 26, in new
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440541+00:00 app[web.1]: settings.BASE_DIR, f'hendrixia/static/captchas/{timestamp}.png'))
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440544+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/captcha/image.py", line 59, in write
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440544+00:00 app[web.1]: return im.save(output, format=format)
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440544+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2148, in save
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440545+00:00 app[web.1]: fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
2022-03-04T11:09:39.440549+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/hendrixia/hendrixia/static/captchas/1646392179.414503.png'
```

Comment: "The problem is at the `image.write()` line"—what problem? Are you getting an error message? Please always include complete error messages. They convey important information. See [ask].

Comment: Ok, I added the traceback